# Is it possible for a new Facebook application to use the legacy Javascript SDK?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Due to reasons out of my control I'm forced to use the legacy Facebook Javascript SDK on a new application. My question is. Is this possible? Des Facebook allows you to use the old legacy SDK on new applications? Or is it deprecated already and cannot be used on new applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook is moving to OAuth 2.0. All apps are required to migrate over by October 1st. This means the old school Facebook JavaScript SDK is going to be phased out as it does not support this. I'm not sure if the old JavaScript library will stop working at that time, but I would definitely migrate to the newer SDK.

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/497/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can still use it.  Its still even [documented](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/oldjavascript/).  Just reference it here:
http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php You obviously run the risk that they will eventually disable it but it is used all over the Internet so they are not likely to permanently kill it anytime soon.